# PHP - multi-level user system loading different content

Tags: php

I am interested in the best way to load content for each user type.

There is a variety of different suggestions on alternative SO posts.

For example, the most useful I have seen is this one:

```
session_start();

//For admin
$_SESSION['type'] = 'admin';

//For user
$_SESSION['type'] = 'user';

//if admin login we will check session and display admin content
if($_SESSION['type']=='admin'){
echo 'Admin content';
}

//if user login we will check session and display user content
if($_SESSION['type']=='user'){
echo 'User content';
}
```

Is this the best way to do it for a website with many pages? If I am interpreting the post correctly, the suggestion here is that ***every*** page of my website should get the user-id (so start with the same code above) and then echo specific HTML content based on that user?

Are there alternative methods?

Comment: check the type in db table itself while login and if you want then save it to session (in case you going for no of pages shuffle)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is perfectly fine. Don't stress on the small details. You could do this in a variety of ways:

```
if($_SESSION['type']=='user'){
    include('includes/user_content.php'); // Ensure users can't access this file directly.
}
```

Additionally, you could just create something like an admin panel:

```
if($_SESSION['type']=='admin'){
    echo '<a href="admin.php">Admin Panel</a>'; // Double check user is an admin in admin.php, and display admin only content there
}
```

Normally on most websites, you would include some header/footer, where you can do most of these checks in there (So you're not repeating these checks on every page). For example:

```
// posts.php
include('header.php');
if ($user['isAdmin']) {
   //Do admin stuff
}

// header.php
session_start();

$user = [];
$user['isAdmin'] = $_SESSION['type'] == 'admin';
$user['name'] = $_SESSION['name'];
```

Comment: Ahh, this is just the right phrasing and delivery of information I needed! Thank you so much. What would go in the 'footer'? Any links to where I can read more about this or something? EDIT: I may be getting confused. Are you referring to a php specific jargon when you talk about 'header'/'footer' or just the standard html header/footer?

Comment: You can do both in the header/footer (HTML and PHP code), whatever you need. `header.php` can contain your initialize code, as well as echoing out the header. You can move the initialize code into a `bootstrap.php` file, and just call `include('bootstrap.php'); include('header.php');` in all your files. Whatever you feel is neatest for you.

Comment: If you need to include a lot of different view data, try including an admin partial inside of your admit if condition. 

if (is_admin()) {
  include 'admin/partialSection.php';
}

Comment: @CodeJunkie Sorry what would this achieve (or what are you referring to even)? I'm a bit new to all this :)